# Wininet & C++: Use FTP to write and append, not overwrite, a file

Tags: c++, wininet

I need my app to connect to my server via FTP and write to a specific file, using the wininet library.

As of right now, everything works fine and the program writes to that file. However, whenever I add a new value to the file, it gets overwritten. I want to write the new data to a new line at the end of the same file.

Here's my code:

```
string user = "apaaaasdasdasdsdsa";

HINTERNET hInternet;
HINTERNET hFtpSession;
hInternet = InternetOpen(NULL, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);
hFtpSession = InternetConnect(hInternet, "ftp.blabla", port, "blablabla", "password", INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, 0, 0);

// Testing
HINTERNET hFile = FtpOpenFile(hFtpSession, "test.html", GENERIC_WRITE , FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_ASCII, 0);
DWORD wb = 0;

char tab2[1024];
strcpy_s(tab2, user.c_str());

InternetWriteFile(hFile, tab2, strlen(tab2), &wb);

//------------------------------

InternetCloseHandle(hFtpSession);
InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);
```

Answer (score 1):

The FTP protocol can't read your mind. It doesn't know that you intend to append to a file. The [WinInet API doesn't directly support appending to files](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/182316). Instead, you need to use `FtpCommand` to send the `APPEND` FTP command directly. See the linked support article for an example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was like i thought.

I'll have to download it, change it in the client with the new data(+the old data) & then reupload it.

Comment: As I've said, if you want to append, then using the `APPEND` command will work fine. Noo need to download if you don't intend to change existing parts of the file. My FTP is rusty so you may wish to read up on whether it's possible to make changes to the middle of the file.